# SQL Agent AD account gets permission denied for ODBC connections in SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, permissions

We have an AD account specifically created for the agent service and when running SSIS packages that connect to databases we get permission denied even though we have granted that account access to the database.  My hunch is that it is something to do with how our security group created the service account in AD.  My question is has anyone experienced this and might know if there are certain settings in AD that could prevent an account from authenticating properly with SQL Server (using Windows authentication)?  If I change the agent service to use another AD account it works and at the SQL Server level they both are granted access to the database with the same permissions.

Comment: check this [Account for the SQL Server Agent Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191543.aspx).

Comment: thank you! - I will go through these recommended settings.